Why does the color of the UI set by FloatVectorProperty appear inconsistent?
theme = bpy.context.preferences.themes[0]

axis_x: FloatVectorProperty(
        name = "axis_x",
        subtype = "COLOR",
        precision=3,
        size = 3,
        min = 0,
        max = 1,
        default = theme.user_interface.axis_x
    )


What should I do?
Thanks!

use subtype = "COLOR_GAMMA"
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/property_subtype_number_array_items.html#rna-enum-property-subtype-number-array-items
theme = bpy.context.preferences.themes[0]

axis_x: FloatVectorProperty(
        name = "axis_x",
        subtype = "COLOR_GAMMA",
        precision=3,
        size = 3,
        min = 0,
        max = 1,
        default = theme.user_interface.axis_x
    )

